# Apply a filter when Gmail is opened

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

"Also apply filter to matching messages"

Checking this box in a Gmail filter ONLY works when creating or editing a filter. Subsequently, the checkbox apparently gets unchecked. I need a filter to be applied EACH time Gmail is invoked. How can I accomplish this without going through a "pretend" filter edit each time?

Answer (score 1):

The filters are only applied to incoming messages.

One way to use a simple filter all the time is to use the Multiple inbox setting. Wiith multiple inboxes you can display 5 other queries as a separate inbox view.

Under settings/inbox change inbox type to "multiple inboxes".  You can then put the logic of the filter you want in the definition of the section. I don't know how complex the query can be.